# 2 spark applications can't consume from same Kafka Topic parrallel using same Group ID

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have a Kafka Topic With multiple partitions. I have a spark application subscribe to that topic using Dstream. When I start another instance of that application first application throws an exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current assignment for partition my-topic-0

and exits.

Comment: I wouldn't think Spark will kill itself during a Consumer group rebalance, but in general, you should scale Spark consumption via num-executors, not launching more than one app independently

Answer (score 0):

In a normal scenario when not using spark and if we start two kafka conumsers with the same group id and if the topic has only one partition the second consumer would become idle/stale.In order to consume the same message from a topic the consumers have to be initiated with different group id's.Same is applicable in the case of spark as well

Comment: I have multiple partitions so consumers shouldn't be idle

Comment: if you are using kafka direct stream utils to stream data from kafka to spark it would be spawn up consumers that would match the number of partitions in kafka. So in your case the first application itself has spawned the consumers that are needed to serve the kafka partitions

Comment: The issue is I have a collect operation Since this will increase the load to driver. Therefore I like to have the ability to spawn another job when the load is high. is it possible